# Do multiple take control effects let me keep a card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I was to cast two "take control of a creature until end of turn" spells, like [Act of Treason](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAct%20of%20Treason%5d), twice on the same creature in the same turn, do I keep it ?

Comment: It can be any two combinations of control untill end of turn spells  or copy

Comment: What leads you to suspect you'd get to keep it? Are you expecting you'd keep it until the turn _after_ or something?

Comment: @doppelgreener My guess would be the idea is the second effect might overwrite the first somehow, and make it forget where to go back to. (Perhaps by analogy to blinking with Cloudshift or one of the ways you *can* keep something by turning it into a new object, but without understanding the underlying rules.)

Answer (score 10):

You will keep the creature until the end of the turn (more precisely, the Cleanup Step). If you cast two separate Acts on the same creature in the same turn, they both have the same duration—"until end of turn"—so both will expire at the same time. They don't add together to let you keep the creature longer.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone i talk to and play with say it works. Based on it returns to the last person that controled it.The first spell would resolve at end secoud spell woud triger resolve.But would be like castining it on a creature you control ,own. only reason i was running it. Maybe i wont tell them.3 of them are masters of the game and all lol.